# Instantiating in Python - Not Callable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a new object, but i receive the error in traceback:

```
    p1 = point(point.x+jumpValue, point.y)
TypeError: 'point' object is not callable
```

I've defined the class in the same file:

```
class point(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

Comment: You've overwritten your class definition with a (non class) point variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a variable with the same name that is *not* the class. Rename the class to use `Point` instead:

```
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

then call it as:

```
p1 = Point(point.x + jumpValue, point.y)
```

Comment: is it convention in python to capitalize class names?

Comment: @MatthewH. Yes it is. See [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for more conventions.

Comment: @MatthewH.: Yes, use CamelCase for class names, lower_case_with_underscores for variable identifiers (function parameters, locals, etc).