# Clearing Internal Variables for Object Class Re-use

Tags: python, class, pylint

I have a class and when I set the name or id to something else I want to zero out other internal variables.

```
    @id.setter
    def id(self, arg):
        '''Set the id to a value, clearing other settings'''
        self.clear(exceptId=arg)

    @name.setter
    def name(self, arg):
        '''Set the name to a value, clearing other settings'''
        self.clear(exceptName=arg)

    def clear(self, exceptId='', exceptName=''):
        self._id = exceptId
        self._name = exceptName
        self._elbclient = ''
        self._elbname = ''
```

The above code works, but when I pylint I get errors such as the following:

```
ec2lib.py:255:8: E1102: self.clear is not callable (not-callable)
ec2lib.py:87:8: W0201: Attribute '_id' defined outside __init__ (attribute-defined-outside-init)
```

What is the proper way to internally deal with housecleaning my variables? Or should I be deleting my objects and then re-creating them?

Comment: You need to initialize all the attributes in the `__init__` method. It's warning you that you're creating a new attribute in a method, rather than reassigning an existing attribute.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033409/instantiating-in-python-not-callable) regarding the "not callable" error. You may have used `self.clear` as an attribute elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

@Barmar has the answer. I wasn't properly initializing all my variables at first in `__init__`.

Regarding the 'not callable' error, I might have had a decorator in front of the method at the time the error was generated.